# WPF application get crashed on pressing right mouse button

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am actually trying to making an Jarvis AI program in c# wpf but i am getting exception in the codes. Actually the problem is when ever in press the right mouse button on my running application, the application gets stuck and crashed can any one can help me in solving this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace jarvis
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used these codes and it actually works

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
```

use the ReleaseCapture method in your form mouse down event Like this

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but if you want to move window with left mouse button just add condition:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        this.DragMove();
}
```

Other mouse buttons causing InvalidOperationException in DragMove() method.
If you want to use right mouse button for window move you have to write custom method for it.

Comment: Actually i have problem with my wpf application, when ever i press right mouse button on the running application it stuck and gets crashed.  how to solve this .

Comment: Try replace **Grid_MouseDown** method with code I mentioned above. This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
      private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
      {
        e.handled = true;  //in your case, prevent right click crash.    
        this.DragMove();
      }
```