# WPF Application crashes when not left clicking an Interaction.Triggers button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have an application with a custom title bar. In the title bar i got a Close button to close the application. This is done via an Interaction.Triggers in WPF directly without any code behind.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="Close" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My problem is that this code will work fine if I left click, but when ever I use a different mouse button let it be right click or middle mouse the application will crash with no error.

I've seen how to avoid the crash when you have the button logic in the code behind

[WPF application get crashed on pressing right mouse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367751/wpf-application-get-crashed-on-pressing-right-mouse-button/47375076)

but this doesn't apply to my case and or I don't know how to apply this knowledge

If anyone knows how to fix it without moving the logic out of XAML please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="DragMove" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This was the problem here, i had this event AND the event in the question on the same object. I fixed it by isolating the DragMove event to the object without the CloseButton and vice verca